# Best method for deploying Drupal 8 modules & themes

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8, drupal-themes

What is the best method for deploying Drupal 8 modules & themes using git flow. I am confused as you need to install them, however, I need to deploy releases of the module/theme up regularly. Sorry if it's a stupid question.

Answer (score 1):

1. Start new feature
2. Install module/do theme stuff
3. Commit, publish/push feature
4. Test what you just did
5. `git flow feature finish` feature back into dev branch (or wherever you want it to go)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure for D8 (should be same as believe) but in D7, I used to start feature first (git flow feature start ), update local codebase, commit and publish the feature. Depending on your git workflow, it might need some extra steps into getting this deployed to production.

Once in production, you update your database usual way.